# There are some strange issues with exporting blender bone animation to UE

Tags: animation, rigging, export, unreal-engine

When I organized the bone mesh in Blender and created an animation for it, there was bone distortion when importing it into UE, [image]

I am using Blender3.0

I am using the MMT plugin

My character bones have bone constraints with the gun. If I remove the bone constraints between them (TB_handI constrained to GUN_mag, TB_handR constrained to GUN_body), it would be correct to create a character bone animation separately and import it into UE. The animation for both the gun and the character is correct, but if I constrain them, the import will become very bad.

[image]

The animation I want is a humanoid skeleton holding a gun, and in my current UE project, I need separate arm animation (FPS) and separate first person gun animation

I want know:

1.How to solve the deformation problem when exporting to UE

2.Is this because the bone mesh exported from blender to UE does not use constraints?

3.What is the correct process for exporting to UE?

I am the first to come into contact with Blender software, and there are many things I am not familiar with. If I ask stupid questions, please point them out and let me know. I will improve myself. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are not standardized and therefore not usually supported by all the import/export chain.

The common workflow is to bake your animations when you want to export. This avoids this kind of issues, and also makes sure every frame is keyed the way you want from your animation software so that it isn't left to the target software that might interpolate things differently otherwise.

Blender's FBX exporter have a Bake Animation option that does bake constraints results by default, even though it doesn't mention it in the UI (the manual does it though: [FBX — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html#id6))

### Baking at export

The fastest, most efficient and non-destructive way to bake animation (especially in bulk if you have actions and NLA strips) is to use the exporter's baking.

When exporting with FBX, make sure to have these options like so:

[image]

- Armature

  - Armature FBXNode Type : Null (so that the armature object itself isn't exported as an extra bone)
  - Only Deform Bones : ON (so that you don't export controllers and mechanical bones that aren't used for deforming)
  - Add Leaf Bones : Off (not needed for game engines)
- Bake Animation : On

  - Key All Bones : On (makes sure even the bones that aren't animated to begin with get keyed down, needed for compatibility with some softwares like UE4 and maybe UE5 still)
  - NLA Strips : depends if you need to export NLA strips as well
  - All Actions : depends if you need to export actions as well
  - Force Start/End Keying : On (helps with some softwares compatibility and data handling)
  - Sampling Rate : 1 so to key down each frame.
  - Simplify : 0 so to keep your animation untouched. Note that the engine will simplify your animation, either during the import or when compiling your final game, both for performance and data size reasons, so don't be surprised if your animation in-game isn't 100% what you made in the animation software.

### Baking before export

You can bake before exporting. It doesn't allow you to bulk export your animation actions and NLA strips, but it allows you to see the resulting animation and check for issues. **It will destructively change your animation and rig, so save in a different file**.

[image]

In Pose Mode, go to the menu *Pose* > *Animation* > *Bake Action*
Or open the Operator Searchbar with <kbd>F3</kbd> and type Bake Action.

- Frame Step : 1
- Only Selected Bones : On if you have a way to easily select only your deform bones, otherwise Off.
- Visual Keying : On (this makes sure to bake bones as they are even with constraints)
- Clear Constraints : On (removes constraints after baking)
- Clear Parents : Off
- Overwrite Current Action : Only if you used NLA strips as layered animation.
- Clean Curves : Off
- Bake Data: Pose

Then hit OK.